# Unable to record in JMeter 3.0 with corporate proxy

Tags: jmeter, record

I am unable to record the operations in the JMeter 3.0. We use corporate proxy hence "No proxy" settings is selected. If I manually configure the proxy setting as IP address and port, unable to get the internet in FF. But, I am able to open the access the internet in IE.

Comment: you are refer to http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Comment: Try using [Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension).

Comment: More details are needed here: "If I manually configure the proxy setting as IP address and port" -- how/where do you configure them? "unable to get the internet in FF" - did you start JMeter recording prior to trying to access internet?

Comment: manually configure means: providing IP address and the port numbers as per documentation. it will be done in FF->Tools->Advanced->network->settings

Comment: No, after configuring proxy, then only I have started JMeter recording

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you follow this documentation:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server

FF uses the proxy settings you configure in it, while IE can use system proxy.

Anyway better use FF and set proxy to point to jmeter, but start jmeter passing your enterprise proxy settings as per reference documentation